# How to maintain SRP (Single Responsibility Principle) with multiple dependencies?

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, single-responsibility-principle

I am confused in a situation where a class must depend on other factors.

For example

```
class Storage:
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = Logger()
        self.client = Elasticsearch()

    def index(document):
        try:
            self.client.index(document)
         except ElasticsearchException as e:
             self.logger.error(str(e))
```

Here my class has to have logger and an `Elasticsearch` object to perform its operations. How can I maintain SRP in this situation where there are possibly two scenarios where my class has to be changed, such as:

1. I switched to different database
2. I switched to different logging library

One could argue that instead of logging here I should let the client class handle the exception. But in a scenario where client is just **`yield`ing** the documents to be inserted and it is accepted to have a failed index operation, the client class doesn't bother about errors. Also, even if I re-throw the exception to client class, the same SRP problem will occur there.

I would appreciate an explanatory answer in my context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think part of the problem is in the title : ".. with multiple dependencies". Your dependencies are highly coupled, because instanciated inside your Storage class.
That's why I would use Dependency Injection (I have 0 python knowledge, might be some typo) :

```
interface StorageClientInterface:
    def index(document)    

interface LoggerInterface:
    def error(Exception e) 

class ElasticSearchStorage implements storageClientInterface:
    def index(document):
        // implements ElasticSearch specific storage logic

class MyDefaultLogger implements LoggerInterface:
    def error(Exception e):
        // implements MyDefaultLogger specific logging logic, totally agnostic from ElascticSearch

class Storage:
    def __init__(self, StorageClientInterface storageClient, LoggerInterface logger):        
        self.client = storageClient
        self.logger = logger

    def index(document):
        try:
            self.client.index(document)
         except Exception as e:
             self.logger.error(e)


// usage
elasticSearch = ElasticSearch()
logger = MyDefaultLogger()
document = Document();
storage = Storage(elasticSearch, logger)    
storage.index(document)
```

this way, your Storage class is not coupled to your storage policy nor logging policy. it just knows it can use these 2 interfaces. if you change your database, you don't have to change anything in your Storage class, as long as this new storage policy implements your StorageClientInterface. Same goes if you change the way you log error. Just instanciate a new concrete Logger, and inject it.

Comment: A number of folks consider [**Dependency Injection is EVIL**](https://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/dependency-injection-is-evil.html). I tend to agree.

Comment: DI is probably not the solution to every problem, but it's clearly not evil, and in this particular problem the poster is facing, it does solve it in an elegant and maintenable way. Even the author of the article you linked says it, despite the fact he clearly dislike DI : "Dependency Injection is only a good idea when a consuming object has a dependency which can be switched at runtime between a number of alternatives, and where the choice of which alternative to use can be made outside of the consuming object and then injected into it. ". This really looks like the problem faced here

Comment: Moreover, i read the article you linked from top to bottom. The only thing I am sure about after this reading is I am not encline to follow any of the advice this man says, when i see the quality of the code he wrote as examples, or the fact he is using a self-coded php framework in business projects when we have very good open-source rock-solid frameworks with thousands of contributors to ensure their quality.

Answer (score 2):

You can do so by introducing additional layers to define abstract APIs to this functionality: one for the database and another for doing the logging. After doing that, your `Storage` class must be restricted to only using them rather than directly calling or any of "real" methods exposed by particular library or module.

That way they (and their clients like the rewritten `Storage` class) wouldn't need to change unless one of the abstract interfaces must be changed for some reason (which won't be necessary if it's designed well). Any concrete implementation of either of these two abstract interfaces will only have one responsibility (i.e. to emulate the abstract API via what's available in some specific logging or database library).

Answer (score 0):

One way you could accomplish this would be to use the [decorator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DecoratorPattern) pattern. The decorator pattern would allow you to encapsulate all the error handling logic in a separate class which could then be used to essentially wrap the behaviour of the decorated class, which in this case would be your Storage class. I don't know Python very well, so excuse any syntax errors, but it would look something like this:

```
class Storage:
    def __init__(self, storageClient):        
        self.client = storageClient

    def index(document):
        self.client.index(document)


class ElasticSearchExceptionPolicy:
    def __init__(self, decorated, logger):
        self.logger = logger
        self.decorated = decorated

    def index(document):
        try:
            decorated.index(document)
        except ElasticsearchException as e:
            self.logger.error(str(e))
```

These objects can then be used like so:

```
elasticSearch = ElasticSearch()
logger = Logger()
storage = Storage(elasticSearch)    
loggedStorage = ElasticSearchExceptionPolicy(storage, logger)
loggedStorage.index(document)
```

You will also probably want to pass the ElasticSearch object and the Logger object into their respective classes if you want to follow the Open/Closed principle.

Comment: Seems to me like you've just moved the problem from one class to another. Also, injecting responsibility into a class via a decorator seems like just a sneaky way of getting around a crucial restriction imposed by the SRP design methodology.

Comment: @martineau Hmm. Maybe it's my misunderstanding of Python. Both classes now only have one reason to change, the Storage class if the storage mechanism changes and the ElasticSearchLogger if the exception policy changes (assuming that the dependencies of the class are injected).

Comment: I've edited the example so that the dependencies are injected.

Comment: What I meant was your proposal just moves the more-than-one-responsibility issue to the decorator class. Note: You also need to be extra precise when talking about decorators in the context of Python, which uses the term differently.

Comment: @martineau Yes, I think it would be difficult to provide the logging and the exception handling separately. Cross cutting concerns are quite difficult to deal with. In .NET I would perhaps use an AOP framework such as PostSharp but even then you would probably have to place the logging with the exception.

Comment: @martineau Actually, looks like the decorator syntax you mention is very similar to AOP.

Comment: I'm sure concepts (and terminology) in the different design methodologies overlap. Maybe the way to reconcile things in this case is to say that there's this other class whose single responsibility is to deal with using these two other classes together in the desired way.

Comment: After a little more research, it seems that others also claim this is a way to maintain SRP—in other words, that the Decorator Pattern used in this way maintains it. One example in the article titled [**How to Implement a Decorator Pattern**](https://web.archive.org/web/20150707165957/http://sam-burns.co.uk/57/how-to-implement-a-decorator-pattern/) where it says this approach "amounts to a good implementation of the Single Responsibility Principle". As I said, I personally I think it's nothing but a dodge, by that's just my opinion.